# Unable to remove data from shared preferences from another activity using Gson

Tags: android, arraylist, gson, sharedpreferences

I am saving a list of custom object in shared preferences using Gson Library like this

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(planmanobraBeanArrayList); 
            prefsEditor.putString("list", json);
            prefsEditor.apply();
```

and to get data from shared preferences I used the following code

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json1 = mPrefs.getString("list", "");
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<PlanmanobraBean>>() {
    }.getType();
    storedata = gson.fromJson(json1, type);
```

This thing is working perfectly but I have a problem removing them from shared preferences.

I want to remove it from shared preferences  on button click and this button is in activity which opens before this activity in which I am storing data. So on button click of previous activity I did this

```
mPrefs = PlaniActivity.this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
                    prefsEditor.putString("list", "");
                    prefsEditor.apply();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor1 = mPrefs.edit();
                    prefsEditor1.putString("platamatBeansArrayList", "");
                    prefsEditor1.apply();
```

I tried to put null value for those lists as I didn't find any other way to remove data from the shared preferences, but the problem is this code is also not working and I am still able to see the stored data from shared preferences.

What should be the proper way of removing data from shared preferences.

Comment: There is a `remove` method. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes that too is not working. Although it works if I remove it from shared preference in the same activity

Comment: Probably because you have `PlaniActivity.this.getPreferences`... You need to store the SharedPreferences in another way. A singleton class is useful for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should be the proper way of removing data from shared preferences.

Using the `remove` method is probably the proper way.

```
mPrefs = PlaniActivity.this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
prefsEditor.remove("list");
```

You also only need one editor, so just keep removing items

```
prefsEditor.remove("platamatBeansArrayList");
```

And you only need to apply or commit once at the very end because all events are queued up.

```
prefsEditor.apply();
```

With regards to using SharedPreferences across Activities, I typically use a Singleton class to handle all that, but `getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences()` might work better than getting the SharedPreferences for just the current Activity.

Comment: how to make it singleton can you tell me that

Comment: I followed this tutorial when I first learned about using the same SharedPreferences throughout the app. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/